# Function to call itself under certain conditions, BASH

Tags: bash

```
function Lab()
{
local result=0
echo

echo 'Please enter your overall percentage for your labs (40% possibility)'
read result

if [ $result != 40 ] || [ $result -lt 0 ]
then
    echo "You have entered a invalid value, please try again."
    Lab #I thought this would call the function again, resetting itself
else
    return $result
fi
}
```

I basically want this function to only be able to take in a value from 0-40. Any value besides this should cause the function to restart itself until the true value is given. I'm pretty new to bash and I've been playing around trying to figure this out for the past day. If anyone has any suggestions that can nudge me in the right direction that would be great!

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any PHP here.  Guessing though that it should be `if [ $result > 40 ] || [ $result < 0 ]` Because `!= 40` is also almost every valid value you have (0-39).

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for recursion; just use a `while` loop. Also, the `return` value of a function isn't used to return data, only to return an exit status. Either set a global variable, or write the result to standard output.

```
lab () {
  echo
  echo 'Please enter your overall percentage for your labs (40% possibility)'
  IFS= read -r result

  while [ "$result" -gt 40 ] || [ "$result" -lt 0 ]; do
    echo "You have entered a invalid value, please try again."
    IFS= read -r result
  done

  echo "$result"
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to store this variable into my main program would call the function by inputting "lab", then store the variable from the function with "LAB=$(lab)"

Comment: Correct; `$(...)` is a *command substitution*; the output of the command is captured and used the same way a parameter expansion would be used.